# How to pass @httppost parameters in apex integration?

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, integration, post

I’m trying to integrate two salesforce orgs. How to pass httppost parameters of method from other salesforce org in apex code please find the below codes it tried but I am getting status 400 badrequest. GET method is working fine, How to pass name parameter from other org?

Mapped class of source org:

```
 // The @RestResource annotation is used at the class level and enables you to expose an Apex class as a REST resource.
    // more details -> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/getContact/*')
    global with sharing class getContact 
    {
        @Httpget
        global static list<contact> fetchContact()
        {
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
            RestResponse res = Restcontext.response;
            //Get input conId from the request string.
            Id conId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            // Get the list of contacts by passing input conId. In this case, it will return only 1 record.
            list<contact> lstcontact =[Select id,Name,Email,MobilePhone from contact where id=:conId ];
            // return back the contact list to calling system.
            return lstcontact ;
        }
        @HttpPost
        global static string createNewContact(String name)
        {
            Contact c=new Contact();
            c.LastName=name;
            insert c;
            return 'contact sucessfully created';
        }

        @HttpDelete
        global static string deleteContact()
        {
            RestRequest req=RestContext.request;
            String ids=req.params.get('Id');
            List<Contact> c=[select id from contact where id=:ids];
            delete c;
            return 'contact deleted successfully';
        }

        @Httpput
        global static string putContact(String ids,String Name)
        {
            Contact c=[select id from contact where id=:ids];
            c.LastName=Name;
            update c;
            return 'contact updated successfully';
        }
    }
```

Controller class of destination org:

```
    public class apexintegration {

public string getContactid {get;set;}

public List<contact> outputlst {get;set;}

public List<Contact> contact {get; set;}

public string JSONResponse {get;set;}

private final string clientid='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
private final string clientsecret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
private final string username='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
private final string password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

public class deserializeResponse
{
    public string id;
    public string access_token;
}

public string returnAccesstoken(apexintegration a)
{
    String reqBody='grant_type=password&client_id='+clientid+'&client_secret='+clientsecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;
    Http h=new http();
    HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
    req.setBody(reqBody);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
    HttpResponse res=h.send(req);
    deserializeResponse resp1=(deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), deserializeResponse.class);
    return resp1.access_token;
}

public void getContact()
{
    apexintegration a=new apexintegration();

    String accesstoken;
    accesstoken=a.returnAccesstoken(a);
    if(accesstoken!=null)
    {
        String endPoint='https://curious-wolf-71m22l-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v1/getContact/';
        Http h2 = new Http();
        HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
        req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
        req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
        req1.setMethod('GET');
        req1.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        HttpResponse res1 = h2.send(req1);
        // store raw JSON response
        JSONResponse = res1.getBody().unescapeCsv().remove('\\');
        contact = (List<Contact>) JSON.deserialize(JSONResponse, List<Contact>.class);

    }
    outputlst= contact;
}

public void createContact()
{
    apexintegration a=new apexintegration();

    String accesstoken;
    accesstoken=a.returnAccesstoken(a);
    if(accesstoken!=null)
    {
        String endPoint='https://curious-wolf-71m22l-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v1/getContact/';
        String body= 'name=saivinaymnprm';
        Http h2 = new Http();
        HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
        req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
        req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
        req1.setMethod('POST');
        req1.setBody(body);
        req1.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        HttpResponse res1 = h2.send(req1);
        JSONResponse = res1.getBody().unescapeCsv().remove('\\');
        String s=(String)JSON.deserialize(JSONResponse, String.class);
        System.debug(s);
}
```

}

Answer (score 7):

The only thing you need to do is retrieving body of the post request, this can be done like in the example below:

```
@HttpPost
global static void processPost() {
    Map<String, Object> requestBody = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString());
    //do something with the resulting map - this is the body of the POST request
}
```

And about request body in the destination organization, you need to pass it like this:

```
String body = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object>{
        'name' => 'some_name'
});
```